# Should I use async/await in my controller?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have watched a few videos on youtube by Les Jackson, on how to create a .net core api. Les uses this approach for a method in his controller

```
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Command>> GetAllCommands()
    {
        var commandItems = _repository.GetAppCommands();
        return Ok(commandItems);
    }
```

However I have just read an article in a book that uses this approach

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Data.CityDataClass>>> GetCities()
{
    return await _repository.GetCities();
}
```

From my thinking is the second method an overkill using the "async" declaration? The first method wont return anything until it has the results anyway.

Thanks

Comment: "The first method wont return anything until it has the results anyway." Yes, but it will keep a thread blocked until the results are ready. In some cases, that's not a problem - in other cases it could be. (Suppose your server is heavily loaded, and this method takes a while... do you want each outstanding call to tie up a thread?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: *"the second method an overkill using the "async" declaration?"* well that depends. If you method is `async` then you **must** await it (unless it has a sync equivalent). If you have the choice of both methods the only real way to tell which is faster is to test it. Basically if you have a centralised service then `async`/`await` can prevent thread starvation. If your service does not suffer from that then the sync equivalent **may** be better as it avoids the overhead of context switching but ultimately the only way to tell is to load test it.

Comment: You may be interested about the pros and cons of [eliding async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can understand this better if you read this article on [I/O threads](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/io-threads-explained/)

> To use asynchronous and parallel features of the .NET properly, you should also understand the concept of **I/O threads**.
>
> Not everything in a program consumes CPU time. When a thread tries to read data from a file on disk or sends a TCP/IP packet through network, the only thing it does is delegate the actual work to a device - disk or network adapter - and wait for results.

> I/O thread is an abstraction intended to hide work with devices behind a simple and familiar concept. The main point here is that you don’t have to work with those devices in a different way, you can think of the pipeline inside them just like it’s a usual CPU consuming thread. At the same time, I/O threads are extremely cheap in comparison with CPU-bound threads, because, in fact, they are merely requests to devices

So with the first way, you are not utilizing the I/O threads but with the second you do, and it's much cheaper.

In your case, when accessing the Database, you are effectively doing an I/O (network) operation. By using asynchronous programming, you are awaiting on an I/O  thread for the I/O (db read) operation to complete, without blocking a thread.

#### Edit (After Liam's comment)

Another interesting read is [async in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth)

> Throughout this entire process, a key takeaway is that **no thread is dedicated to running the task**. Although work is executed in some context (that is, the OS does have to pass data to a device driver and respond to an interrupt), there is no thread dedicated to waiting for data from the request to come back. This **allows the system to handle a much larger volume of work** rather than waiting for some I/O call to finish.

For even more information [check the asynchronous overhead here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-performance-characteristics-of-async-methods/)

> 1. If the async method completes synchronously the performance overhead is fairly small.
> 2. If the async method completes synchronously the following memory overhead will occur: for async Task methods there is no overhead, for async Taskmethods the overhead is 88 bytes per operation (on x64 platform).
> 3. ValueTask can remove the overhead mentioned above for async methods that complete synchronously.
> 4. A ValueTask-based async method is a bit faster than a Task-based method if the method completes synchronously and a bit slower otherwise.
> 5. A performance overhead of async methods that await non-completed task is way more substantial (~300 bytes per operation on x64 platform).

Comment: Where are device, disk or network involved in the OP question? They could be used by the `GetAppCommands` or `GetCities` methods, but there is no evidence of such behavior. Please clarify that.

Comment: IO threads is part of the answer but not the whole picture. `async`/`await` also frees up thread pool threads which aids thoughput on a centralised service but also adds overhead in the form of context switching and state machine storage.

Comment: Agreed! I added some more information for anyone to check on the overhead (which is minimal) and some in depth async articles too.